# "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" when trying to process image

Tags: android, image, sockets

I am making an app that sends an image to a server but the reception client might have a have problem. Logcat shows `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread`. I don't know how to resolve this. Here is my code

onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IV);
    BitmapImage.execute((Runnable)imageView);
}
```

Receiving Image and show

```
public class BitmapImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView bmImage;
    DataInputStream dis;
    OutputStream fos;

    int len;
    int size = 8012;
    byte[] data = new byte[size];
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        Bitmap size = null;
        Bitmap mBitmap = null;
        bmImage = (ImageView)params[0];

        try {
            Log.d("TCP", "C: Connecting...");
            Socket server = new Socket(IPN, 2965);
            fName = "img.TIFF";
            try {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(server.getOutputStream())), true);
                out.println(command);
                dirPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
                File filepath = new File(dirPath);
                if (!filepath.isDirectory()) {
                    filepath.mkdirs();
                    Log.i("tag", "디렉토리 생성");
                }

                Log.i("tag", "m : " + "파일 생성");
                dis = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                rf = new File(filepath + "/" + fName);
                fos = openFileOutput(fName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                while ((len = dis.read(data)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(data, 0, len);
                    Log.i("tag", "tag : " + "수신중");
                }
                Log.i("tag", "tag : " + "수신 완료");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("tag", "err : " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                dis.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
        }

        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(Uri.fromFile(rf), "r");
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            size = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, (S*mBitmap.getWidth()), (S*mBitmap.getHeight()), true);

            Log.i("tag", "출력 완료");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", "오류났당 -> " + e);
        }
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

I thought the size of the file is the problem so I changed the file format but it did not solve this. Disunite receiving portion and an output portion. That also can't solve this.

Finally I want received some second application, and I will use android remote PC.

Comment: `but the reception client might have a have problem` ?? I think the sending client has a problem.

Comment: I think you are checking wrong file. since your calling sever in Background thread so no way its gona block the UI thread.

Comment: `BitmapImage.execute((Runnable)imageView);`. Does that compile?  Your instance has the same name as it's class. Strange. Where are you creating your clas instance with `new`?

Answer (score 1):

add this line in manifest under the application

```
<application
      android:largeHeap="true" >
</application>
```

it will help to solve memory problem while loading images.